# How to create a cmd/PowerShell alias that can be used with arguments

Tags: powershell, cmd

I wanna be able to execute the following command without having to type that much

```
php E:\zftool\zftool.phar create project E:\test
```

So I created a zf.cmd file containing this

```
php E:\zftool\zftool.phar %1 %2 %3
```

But when I enter

```
zf create project E:\test
```

It only executes the alias

```
php E:\zftool\zftool.phar
```

Any ideas on how can I fix that?
Thanks in advance.

================================================================================

**[Edit]:**

The solution proposed by [JPBlanc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608772/jpblanc) solved my problem, but if you create the function at runtime you'll lost its definition after closing PowerShell window.

To make it persist for every session, you have to add that function to your profile:

1. Open Windows PowerShell.
2. Enter `notepad $profile` command. If it opens an empty unnamed file, then you
       should close it and create a new $profile with `New-Item -path
       $profile -type file` command.
3. Paste your function code inside the file you've just created, save it and you're ready to go.

If receive any error messages like

> "File cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on
>   this system"

that can be fixed by entering

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` or `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I would **not** use a `.cmd` file. I would create a PowerShell *function* `zf` with 3 parameters. The `zf` function will use `Invoke-expression` CmdLet or `&`.

```
zf ($p1, $p2, $p3)
{
  [string]$pathToPHPExe = "C:\PHP\PHP.exe"
  [string]$pathToFILE = "E:\zftool\zftool.phar"
  [Array]$arguments = $pathToFILE, $p1, $p2, $p3

  & $pathToPHPExe $arguments
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked great. Didn't know that we could code stuff like that in PowerShell. I'll also edit my post later to explain how to make that function persist for other sessions using $profile (something that I've just learn).

Answer (score 0):

If that's the entirety of your batch file, it should work fine.  What is the output on the command line?  With echo on, it should display what it's trying to run.

My first thought, though, as to why it might not work is that perhaps when it's calling php, you have a php.cmd file in your path earlier than your php.exe, and that php.cmd only passes the first argument (i.e., it only has a line like `php.exe %1`).

In your batch file, try explicitly running `php.exe` and see if that helps.

Comment: Hmm...no, I don't have any php.cmd in my path. But thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing missing up there:
the 'function' keyword that defines the code block as a function.

```
function zf ($p1, $p2, $p3) {
    #your code here
}
```